# Why is my available disk space so low?

Tags: linux, disk-space-utilization

I'm trying to check the free disk space on a virtual CentOS server (6 GB RAM, 400 GB disk space, 3x CPU)

This is the output of `df -hT`:

```
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vzfs      reiserfs  242G  578M   36G   2% /
none           devtmpfs  4,0G  4,0K  4,0G   1% /dev
```

As you can see the available disk space is only 36 GB, but with only 0.5 GB of actual data. (Also the total space of 242 GB doesn't match the promised 400 GB, but that is not what worries me)

The percentage again looks plausible, also checking `du` returns roughly the same usage amount.

I was able to use `dd` to create a 50 GB file, so I guess it is only the "Avail" value, which is wrong.

What is going on here?

**EDIT:** Over night the problems seems to have fixed itself. The server was not rebooted. I'm 99% sure this has something to do with the virtualization the hoster is doing, but if someone can shed some light on this, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Seems like you should be addressing this with the hosting company.

Comment: As @Iain said we are not the hosting company and there is no way that we can know why you don't have the space that your plan offers. \

Comment: The weird thing is: It looks like I have the ordered space, but `df` shows implausible values.

Comment: Perhaps the real question is: How is the available space determined...

Comment: well, normally you expect Used + Avail to be a little less than Size, but only by a couple gigs. Not the huge difference you're seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `quotacheck -vguma` and see if there's a quota established for that filesystem. 
Also look in the top directory of that mount point and see if there are any files with the word "quota" in them.

Also, run an fsck on the filesystem and reboot. could be a corrupted filesystem.

Comment: Quotas are enabled, but not set: `Disk quotas for user root (uid 0): none` (I used `quota` instead of `quotacheck`, the latter complained about not using journaled quota and potentially damaging the root mountpoint)

Comment: Run an fsck and reboot ....

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't make a difference. Anyway, thank you for trying to help me!

Comment: any luck figuring this out?

Comment: No, unfortunately not, but since this problem has resolved itself, I'm marking your answer as correct, until someone finds an explanation.

Comment: resolved itself? how? did it resolve after a reboot?

Comment: No, there was no reboot. I checked `uptime`, just a few hours have passed.